# How to identify a set of n-highest intercepts after running a series of mixed models

Tags: mixed-model, multiple-comparisons

I have a data frame that contains multiple dependent variables and multiple entries per subject. I don't have any regressors in my model, I am just interested in the global intercept. For each of my variables, I fit a random-intercepts model which allows me to account for within-subject and between-subject variance, After running all mixed models, I would like to use a method that allows me to identify a set of dependent variables associated with significantly higher intercepts than the rest.

Consider this example with different days, different subjects and how much of a particular food each subjects eats:

| value | subject | food | variable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jane | Apple | Monday |
| 2 | Jane | Steak | Monday |
| 3 | Jane | Fruity Loops | Monday |
| 2 | John | Apple | Monday |
| 3 | John | Steak | Monday |
| 1 | John | Fruity Loops | Monday |
| 2 | Jane | Apple | Tuesday |
| 3 | Jane | Steak | Tuesday |
| 4 | Jane | Fruity Loops | Tuesday |
| 3 | John | Apple | Tuesday |
| 4 | John | Steak | Tuesday |
| 2 | John | Fruity Loops | Tuesday |
| 3 | Jane | Apple | Wednesday |
| 4 | Jane | Steak | Wednesday |
| 5 | Jane | Fruity Loops | Wednesday |
| 4 | John | Apple | Wednesday |
| 5 | John | Steak | Wednesday |
| 3 | John | Fruity Loops | Wednesday |

For each of the variables (days) we could fit a model like such:

*value ~ 1 + (1 | subject)*

Which in plain english translates to "I am not interested in how much of a particular food has been eaten and I also don't care how much and what each subject eats. I want to know **how much the average person eats on this day**". Finally, after setting up a mixed model for each day, I would like to identify the day(s) on which people eat the most. Does anyone have an idea how to do this?